# Let $k$ be a field. Can all the ideals in $k[X,Y]$ be generated by at most two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals

> Let $k$ be a field. Can all the ideals in $k[X,Y]$ be generated by at most two elements?

I don't think it can. I thought of the ideal $(X^2,XY,Y^2)$ and I think it can't be generated by only two elements, but I'm having trouble trying to prove it.

I know it can't be generated by only 1 polynomial, because if it could, that polynomial would divide all three elements and $\gcd(X^2,XY,Y^2)=1$.

For the 2 polynomial case, I tried to prove by contradiction. If $(X^2,XY,Y^2)=(F,G)$ we would have that

$$F(X,Y)=A_1(X,Y)X^2+A_2(X,Y)XY+A_3(X,Y)Y^2$$
$$G(X,Y)=B_1X^2+B_2XY+B_3Y^2$$
$$X^2=C_1F+C_2G, \hspace{2mm} XY=D_1F+D_2G, \hspace{2mm} Y^2=E_1F+E_2G$$

And I tried to solve this to see if I could get any contradiction, but the calculations got too big and I think this is the wrong way to prove it.

So what's the proper way to prove this specific example? If you have an easier example, I would appreciate it too.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two elements $f,g\in k[x,y]$ which generate the ideal $(x^2,xy,y^2)$. This gives a surjection $k[x,y]^{\oplus 2}\to (x^2,xy,y^2)$, and applying the functor $-\otimes_{k[x,y]} (k[x,y]/(x,y))$ gives a surjection $k^2\to (x,y)^2/(x,y)^3$. But this last quotient is spanned by the classes of $x^2$, $xy$, and $y^2$ modulo $(x,y)^3$, and these elements are linearly independent, so it has dimension three. But there is no surjective $k$-linear map $k^2\to k^3$, and thus $(x^2,xy,y^2)$ cannot be generated by two elements.